# Swig: Wrapping a vector of structs (nested in a class and namespace)

Tags: python, c++, swig

Here is a reduced example of my problem:

I have a struct, within a class, which is in a namespace. In the class, there is a vector of my_struct's.

```
namespace my_namespace {
    class my_class {
    public:
        struct my_struct {
            int a;
            int b;
        }

        std::vector<my_struct> my_vector;
    }    
}
```

There is also a function (in example.h) that returns my_vector. The code above is #included in example.h. I'm trying to wrap this using SWIG so that I can access my_vector in Python. My SWIG file looks like this at the moment. I'm trying to use the nested workaround method.

```
%module Example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

// Redefine struct class in global scope in order for SWIG to generate proxy class
// Only SWIG parses this definition
struct my_struct
{
    int  a;
    int  b;
};
%nestedworkaround my_namespace::my_class::my_struct;

// We fooled SWIG into thinking that DtProgramMapping is a global struct
// Now we need to trick the C++ compiler into understanding this apparent global type
%{
typedef my_namespace::my_class::my_struct my_struct;
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%template(MyStructVector) std::vector<my_namespace::my_class::my_struct>;

%include "example.h"
```

If I define my_struct in example.h (without the namespace and class) everything works fine. But unfortunately in my application I'm not able to remove those. With this current code I get back a list of Swig objects that look like:

```
<Swig Object of type 'std::vector< my_namespace::my_class::my_struct >::value_type *' at 0x7f82...>
```

I want to be getting back a list of 'proxy of Swig Object...', as I'm able to access the members in that:

```
<Example.my_struct; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< my_struct >::value_type *' at 0x7f82...> >
```

Comment: What version of swig do you use?

Comment: @AlexanderSolovets I'm using version 2.0.12

Comment: Nested classes aren't supported in 2.0 - http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nested_classes

Comment: @AlexanderSolovets Right, that's why I was using the nestedworkaround, which is also described in the docs. I've since switched to version 3.0, and removed the nested workaround code from the interface file, but still getting the same outcome